# VS code "No module named" error (I created the module and the code is in Python)

Tags: python

I just started programming with VS code and I created a module for my project. I'm trying to import my module into one of my files and the import line doesn't have any errors, but when I try to run the code I get the "No module named" error. I have already tried to solve the problem using several different sources but it seems like I'm doing everything just like the sources are recommending. [Image for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUfOz.png) I'm trying to import "Document" from "docs" into the "server_mod.py" file but get the error that I mentioned earlier when I try to run the code.
I'm able to provide more information if necessary.

Any help is appreciated :)

I have tried to create a new module in a different file and I have tried to restart VS code. The other solutions that I found online were already implemented in my code.

EDIT: the code that I used to import the module:

```py
from docs import Document
```

Comment: can you paste the code that you used to import the module

Answer (score 0):

`from x import y` applies to objects and functions inside the file.
for example:

```py
# docs/y.py
x = 2
```

```py
# main.py
from docs.y import x
print(x) # result: 2
```

what you want instead is this:

```py
import docs.document
```

or,

```py
from docs.document import *
```

to import everything at once

Comment: I still get the error after trying to import like you recommended.

Comment: wait what file are you importing from